# Setting variable value dynamically in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

we are running K means clustering in BigQuery using below syntax.

In the first step we are running k means clustering for k values 1 to 7 and storing k value along with dbi statistic in "grid" table.

| k | dbi |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.16 |
| 2 | 2.22 |

In the second step k means clustering is run using k value that has least dbi statistic stored in "grid" table (k=1 as per above example)

step 1:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  ('CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ' ||dataset_name|| '.grid (dbi float64, k int64)');
WHILE
  n < 7 DO
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  "CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL " ||dataset_name|| ".clusters OPTIONS(model_type='kmeans',num_clusters=@x,distance_type = 'euclidean',standardize_features = TRUE,kmeans_init_method = 'KMEANS++') AS SELECT * EXCEPT(Id) FROM " ||dataset_name|| ". raw_data"
USING
  n AS x;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  "insert " ||dataset_name|| ".grid SELECT davies_bouldin_index, @y as k FROM ML.EVALUATE(model "||dataset_name||".clusters)"
USING
  n AS y;
SET
  n = n + 1;
END WHILE
  ;
```

step 2:

```
SET k = 'SELECT k FROM (SELECT dbi,k, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY dbi) AS ranking FROM '||dataset_name||'.grid) WHERE ranking =1'; 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE k;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  ("CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL "||dataset_name||".clusters OPTIONS(model_type='kmeans',num_clusters=@x,distance_type = 'euclidean',standardize_features = TRUE,kmeans_init_method = 'KMEANS++') AS SELECT * EXCEPT(Id) FROM "||dataset_name||".raw_table")
USING 
  k AS x; 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  
  ('SELECT * FROM '||dataset_name||'.grid_demographics_emr"');
```

i'm getting below error when i run step 2

```
Query error: Option num_clusters value has type STRING which cannot be coerced to expected type INT64; failed to set 'num_clusters' in OPTIONS()
```

while I know what the error is I'm not sure on how to fix it. I want to set the k value using dynamic dataset, coding as above is actually assigning string to k. hence, it is failing. I'm looking if there are any other ways to set k value using dynamic dataset in BigQuery?

Thanks